# How do you solve "BUILD FAILURE: No main.py(C) found in your app directory" error?

Tags: buildozer

I am getting an error in Ubuntu 23.10 when i want to build an apk with buildozer. the error reads like,

"BUILD FAILURE: No main.py(c) found in your app directory. This
file must exist to act as the entry point for you app. If your app is
started by a file with a different name, rename it to main.py or add a
main.py that loads it."

The main.py file is in the same directory as the buildozer.spec file. I have tried to put the directory path in the buildozer.spec by replacing the "." under source_dir = . but it never helped. Find the screenshot showing what i am explaining.[BUILD FAILURE: No main.py(c)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELLB3.png)

I was building an apk file with buildozer instead iam getting no main.py file in app directory

Comment: The error was from buildozer.spec file, i was supposed to leave the source files list empty instead of an asterisk(*) to include all source files.                                                                                                                                                      ''# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts =                                                                  "